# Limiting resource usage for debugging an application on linux

Tags: linux, debugging, valgrind

I have a C/C++ application that crashes only under heavy loads. I normally use valgrind and gprof to debug memory leaks and profiling issues. Failure rate is like about 100 in a million runs. This is consistent.
Rather than reproduce the traffic to my application, can I superficially limit the resources available to the debug build of the application running within valgrind somehow?

Comment: When you see heavy loads, are you CPU bound or IO bound? RAM? Also, I assume you have looked into the core files.

Comment: I don't have the core files(deployed elsewhere) and I'm not able to reproduce this inhouse.

Answer (score 2):

`ulimit` can be used from bash to set hard limits on some resources.

Comment: All shells should have `ulimit`, not just Bash...  http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ulimit.html  As an aside to OP, the `ulimit` shell builtin uses the  `getrlimit` and `setrlimit` functions, which you can use directly in C/C++ if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Linux only some of the memory ulimits actually work.

For example, I don't think `ulimit -d` which is supposed to limit the data segment (which I think is RSS) really works.

As I recall from my experience with trying to keep Evolution (the email client) under control, `ulimit -v` (the virtual memory) was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a race condition - have you tried the 'helgrind' valgrind tool?